# firebase functions set config cannot set with JSON file

Tags: google-cloud-functions

Can anyone help, when I try to set firebase functions config on PowerShell by using the env JSON file, it does not allow me to do that. My command is firebase functions:config:set env="$(cat env.json)"  it return me

`firebase functions:config:set env="$(cat env.json)"  Error: Invalid argument, each config value must have a 2-part key (e.g. foo.bar).`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on the description, you are required to have a 2-part key to make it work. You might probably have an issue on your env.json.

Check and see if your env.json looks something like this (where we have a "main" key called **env** and then multiple values inside it):

```
{
  "env": {
    "var1": {
         "a": "a",
         "b": "b"
    },
    "var2": "asd"
  }
}
```